# Problem installing package for python

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to install a python package called libsbml. The instructions on the website tell me to use the following commands and that this should be enough to install the package:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/fbergman:/libsbml/xUbuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/python-libsbml.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-libsbml
```

However I get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-libsbml : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Despite having the latest version of libstdc++6 isntalled. Could anybody advice me on how to get this package installed?

------------edit ------------
Here is a link to the instructions I am using: http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Afbergman%3Alibsbml&package=python-libsbml

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Are you using xubuntu or debian? Why are you using Ubuntu repo instead of Debian one? Please check again the [obs page](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Afbergman%3Alibsbml&package=python-libsbml) instructions

Comment: Would you consider providing link to these instructions?

Comment: @MatthewRock  sure - I have edited the question above

Comment: @andcoz I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @user3059024 What is the result of `dpkg -s libstdc++6 | grep Version`?

Comment: @user3059024,  you can't use this command --- `sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/fbergman:/libsbml/xUbuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/python-libsbml.list"
`. As the suffix in the url explains, this is a xUbuntu repo

Comment: @ Madhavan Kumar I think the `x`in this case means *any*. (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the libSBML package in Ubuntu 14.04, first install the Python development packages and the Pip install system:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip
```

Then install the libSBML dependencies and development libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev 
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install bzip2 libbz2-dev
```

Finally, install libSBML:

```
sudo pip install python-libsbml
```